# Парсинг файла php

Tags: файлы, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Нужно из имеющегося файла (расширение не XML и размер может быть как малым, там и большим) вытянуть данные и записать в БД. Сделать это нужно как можно более рациональным и быстрым способом. Мне не нужен код, просто нужно хорошее наставление.

Comment: Какая структура у этих данных? Если ничего общего она не имеет с HTML или XML, то скорее всего, что придётся довольствоваться регулярками.

Comment: Расширение файла .csv

Comment: @Neek05 http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Как по мне, отличнейшее наставление это [Поиск Google][1].


  [1]: https://www.google.com/search?q=parse+csv+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наставление.

1. Определите структуру данных. Попытайтесь найти в ней закономерность. Возможно, эта закономерность уже прописана в стандартных расширениях php (xml, yml, json, csv, etc.). Так вы сэкономите ресурсы и время разработки.
2. Если файл нестандартный, то попытайтесь найти локальные закономерности. Например, блоки разделяются переносом строки, а внутри блоков информация - пробелами, скобками и точками.
   Тогда используйте построчное чтение файла, а строку разбивайте exploadом.
3. Совсем плохой случай, когда инфа перемешана с кучей бесполезной инфы. 
   Тогда придется поискать хоть какие-то зацепки. Например, что имя-фамилия-отчество пишется русскими буквами сразу перед датой рождения.
   Тут тоже регулярки.
4. Отвратительный случай. Закономерности нет, зацепки все время разные.
   Эффективно распарсить такой текст не выйдет:) Попросите более структурированный.